# How to modify a multi same keys dictionnary to a unique key dictionnary in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have created a dictionary based on few texts. It looks like:

```py
word_dict = {
  Accompagner: "Accompagner",
  Belfort: "Belfort",
  pour: "pour",
  ACC: "ACC",
  et: "et",
  optimisation: "Optimisation",
  de: "de",
  flux: "flux",
  d: "d",
  un: "une",
  et: "testA",
  et: "test2",
};
```

I want to get something like:

```py
word_dict = {
  Accompagner: "Accompagner",
  Belfort: "Belfort",
  pour: "pour",
  ACC: "ACC",
  et: ["et", "testA", "test2"],
  optimisation: "Optimisation",
  de: "de",
  flux: "flux",
  d: "d",
  un: "une",
};
```

Is it possible to do such a thing?

Thank you

Comment: There isn't such thing as "same keys dictionary". You can try to init it like this and you will see the second entry will overwrite the first value

Comment: Sure. Main problem is probably to read the original dictionary (as a string like in the question or something else) in a data structure in Python (a dict won't work).

Comment: Can you show us how did you created this dict? From the formatting I guess "et" can be a instance of some specific class, in such case this could be possible bacuse every instance has unique id that could be used as hash

Comment: in the first how you take the first result from the user ? to be able to help you, because for sure you will not take it like this because this is not valid dictionary

Comment: Thanks, I changed my dictionnary to a pandas DataFrame I changed a little bit my code and it's okay now. Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

You probably would want the original word_dict to be a list of tuples, then, while iterating that list, if the first element of the tuple exists in the dictionary you're creating you grab the existing value and create a list with it and the newfound value, or if it doesn't exist you just add it normally. Now you can worry about whether you create all values as a list and just append the repeated keys and finally, do a last iteration of the dict you created, if the len of the value is one leave the value alone without it being a list or add all values normally then create the list on repeats or append if already created.

```py
word_dict = [
    ('Accompagner', "Accompagner"),
    ('Belfort', "Belfort"),
    ('pour', "pour"),
    ('ACC', "ACC"),
    ('et', "et"),
    ('optimisation', "Optimisation"),
    ('de', "de"),
    ('flux', "flux"),
    ('d', "d"),
    ('un', "une"),
    ('et', "testA"),
    ('et', "test2"),
];

myDict = {}

for key, value in word_dict:
    if key in myDict:
        if type(myDict[key]) != list:
            # Create the list with the old
            myDict[key] = [myDict[key]]
        myDict[key].append(value)
    else:
        myDict[key] = value
```

```
{
  "Accompagner": "Accompagner",
  "Belfort": "Belfort",
  "pour": "pour",
  "ACC": "ACC",
  "et": ["et", "testA", "test2"],
  "optimisation": "Optimisation",
  "de": "de",
  "flux": "flux",
  "d": "d",
  "un": "une"
}
```

Answer (score -4):

In Python, dictionary keys must be unique. Therefore, you cannot have multiple entries with the same key in a dictionary. However, you can achieve a similar structure using a dictionary where each key maps to a list of values. Here's how you can modify your original dictionary to achieve the desired structure:

```py
word_dict = {
    'Accompagner': 'Accompagner',
    'Belfort': 'Belfort',
    'pour': 'pour',
    'ACC': 'ACC',
    'et': 'et',
    'optimisation': 'Optimisation',
    'de': 'de',
    'flux': 'flux',
    'd': 'd',
    'un': 'une',
    'et': 'testA',
    'et': 'test2'
}

# Create a new dictionary to store the modified structure
unique_key_dict = {}

for key, value in word_dict.items():
    if key not in unique_key_dict:
        unique_key_dict[key] = [value]
    else:
        unique_key_dict[key].append(value)

print(unique_key_dict)
```

This code will result in a dictionary where keys are unique, and each key maps to a list of values:

```py
{
    'Accompagner': ['Accompagner'],
    'Belfort': ['Belfort'],
    'pour': ['pour'],
    'ACC': ['ACC'],
    'et': ['et', 'testA', 'test2'],
    'optimisation': ['Optimisation'],
    'de': ['de'],
    'flux': ['flux'],
    'd': ['d'],
    'un': ['une']
}
```

Now, you have a dictionary where each key is unique, and the associated values are stored in a list.

Comment: Obvious ChatGPT is obvious and you didn't even test the code.

Comment: Yep as Daviid said, it won't work, you cannot init dict with this same key